# Android: cannot resolve symbol FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to android and using firebase for an android app.
I have added the firebase realtime database by using the firebase assistant provided by android studio.
When I try proceeding with adding firebase code, android studio shows the error "cannot resolve..." with anything firebase related.

```
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

I have looked for a solution everywhere, re-added firebase multiple times and it still won't work. Of course, I have checked for the correct dependencies in the gradle scripts.

This is what it looks like currently:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
```

I would really appreciate some help. I might have missed something small due to being a beginner.

Comment: please add this line before accessing data base reference like
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);


 
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("dbname");

Comment: not sure what this is supposed to do because android studio still won't recognise anything with "FirebaseDatabase" @VinodMakode

Comment: did you sync your project ?

Comment: I have multiple times, as well as cleaning the project @Ashish